# Why does `git svn clone` not convert all SVN branches?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have an SVN repository that I'm converting to a Git repo using `git svn`.  The process does not consistently convert SVN branches to Git branches, and I'm trying to figure out why.

I start with an SVN repo in the directory `svn_source/`.  This is a proper repo, not a working copy.  If I checkout a working copy into `svn_wc/`, I can list its branches explicitly:

```
~$ svn checkout file://~/svn_source/ ~/svn_wc/
~$ cd svn_wc/
~/svn-wc$ ls -A1h branches/
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
2.0
3.0
3.0-alpha
3.0-beta
3.1-test
```

When I then use `git svn clone` to clone the SVN repo (not the working copy) into a full Git repo,

```
~$ git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata file://~/svn_source/  ~/git_full/
```

only three of the SVN branches are converted into remote branch references under `~/git_full/.git/refs/remotes/origin/`:

```
~/git_full/.git$ tree refs/     
refs/
├── heads/
│   └── master
├── remotes/
│   └── origin/
│       ├── 2.0
│       ├── 3.0-beta
│       ├── tags/
│       └── 3.1-test
└── tags/

5 directories, 4 files
```

Why are only these three converted?  I've run the `git svn clone` three times, and it's always these.  There's nothing special about them that I know of.

Comment: Please show the output of `git show-ref`  instead of `tree refs/`. Git doesn't store branches only in files below `.git/refs` but also in other places.

Comment: `git show-ref` shows all of the expected branches as `<hash> refs/remotes/origin/<branchname>` lines.  So I guess `git svn clone` is cloning every SVN branch.  Any idea why those three branches might be singled out to go in `.git/refs/` explicitly?

Comment: See my answer plus: The "older" branches have been packed into one file because they did not change in the latest SVN-revisions. the newer branches are updated more often in the latest revision and hence not (yet) packed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tree refs/` command might not show all refs because git eventually packs them into the file `.git/packed-refs`. This is explained in the [git pack-refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) manual:

> Traditionally, tips of branches and tags (collectively known as refs)
> were stored one file per ref in a (sub)directory under $GIT_DIR/refs
> directory. While many branch tips tend to be updated often, most tags
> and some branch tips are never updated. When a repository has hundreds
> or thousands of tags, this one-file-per-ref format both wastes storage
> and hurts performance.

To show everything use either
[`git show-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref) or [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).